# React Native IOS Run Error - (in target 'RNFBMessaging' from project 'Pods')

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase, podfile

I did not have any problems with the Android application, I successfully completed all the steps and published my application.

But I am getting an error while running the App in IOS emulator.

I will be glad if you can help me how to solve this problem. thanks

**Podfile**

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

production = ENV["PRODUCTION"] == "1"

target 'cmsio' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :production => production,
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

  pod 'RNFBMessaging', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAccuracy', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAccuracy"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse"
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications"  

  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  $RNGoogleMobileAdsAsStaticFramework = true

  target 'cmsioTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

**Error Message**

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/sirket/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cmsio-doadelmxvtbipqeduigsnvnzbamx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFBMessaging.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNFBMessagingSerializer.o /Users/sirket/Desktop/android/cmsio/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessagingSerializer.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNFBMessaging' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

Being able to run the application

Comment: Getting the same error here. Project running through xcode but, yarn ios giving this error.

Comment: @abdullahfarooqui did you fixed it, it would be helpful if you mention the fixes

Answer (score 0):

do you have this in podfile ?

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

and in AppDelegate.m

```
  [FIRApp configure];
```

you can refer here https://rnfirebase.io/

Comment: its there i am still getting the same.